# Implementing a custom objective function in Keras

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a custom Keras objective function:

> in 'Direct Intrinsics: Learning Albedo-Shading Decomposition by Convolutional Regression', Narihira et al.

[image: (4) and (6)]

This is the sum of equations `(4)` and `(6)` from the previous picture. `Y*` is the ground truth, `Y` a prediction map and `y = Y* - Y`.

This is my code:

```py
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
  #Eq. (4) Scale invariant L2 loss
  y = y_true - y_pred
  h = 0.5 # lambda
  term1 = K.mean(K.sum(K.square(y)))
  term2 = K.square(K.mean(K.sum(y)))
  sca = term1-h*term2    
  #Eq. (6) Gradient L2 loss
  gra = K.mean(K.sum((K.square(K.gradients(K.sum(y[:,1]), y)) + K.square(K.gradients(K.sum(y[1,:]), y)))))
  return (sca + gra)
```

However, I suspect that the equation (6) is not correctly implemented because the results are not good. Am I computing this right?

Thank you!

Edit:

I am trying to approximate (6) convolving with Prewitt filters. It works when my input is a chunk of images i.e. `y[batch_size, channels, row, cols]`, but not with `y_true` and `y_pred` (which are of type `TensorType(float32, 4D)`).

My code:

```py
def cconv(image, g_kernel, batch_size):
  g_kernel = theano.shared(g_kernel)
  M = T.dtensor3()
  conv = theano.function(
      inputs=[M],
      outputs=conv2d(M, g_kernel, border_mode='full'),
  )
  accum = 0
  for curr_batch in range (batch_size):
      accum = accum + conv(image[curr_batch])
  return accum/batch_size


def gradient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  y = y_true - y_pred

  batch_size = 40

  # Direction i
  pw_x = np.array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]).astype(np.float64)
  g_x = cconv(y, pw_x, batch_size)

  # Direction j
  pw_y = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]).astype(np.float64)
  g_y = cconv(y, pw_y, batch_size)

  gra_l2_loss = K.mean(K.square(g_x) + K.square(g_y))

  return (gra_l2_loss)
```

The crash is produced in:

```
    accum = accum + conv(image[curr_batch])
```

...and error description is the following one:

> *** TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "custom_models.py:836" at index 0 (0-based)', 'Expected an array-like
>   object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function
>   on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')

How can I use y (y_true - y_pred) as a numpy array, or how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SIL2

```py
term1 = K.mean(K.square(y))
term2 = K.square(K.mean(y))
[...]
```

One mistake spread across the code was that when you see `(1/n * sum())` in the equations, it is a **mean**. Not the mean of a sum.

### Gradient

After reading your comment and giving it more thought, I think there is a confusion about the gradient. At least I got confused.

There are two ways of interpreting the gradient symbol:

1. The [gradient of a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/gradient-of-a-vector-field) where `y` should be differentiated with respect to the parameters of your model (usually the weights of the neural net). In previous edits I started to write in this direction because that's the sort of approach used to trained the model (eg. gradient descent). But I think I was wrong.
2. The pixel intensity gradient in a picture, as you mentioned in your comment. The diff of each pixel with its neighbor in each direction. In which case I guess you have to translate the example you gave into Keras.

To sum up, `K.gradients()` and `numpy.gradient()` are not used in the same way. Because numpy implicitly considers `(i, j)` (the row and column indices) as the two input variables, while when you feed a 2D image to a neural net, every single pixel **is** an input variable. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I managed to solve the eq. 4 by deleting the sum as you said, but I am still stuck with the eq. 6. The problem is that I don’t know how to obtain the i and j directions of my y (a RGB image) in Keras syntax. Computing the gradient of i and j of y using numpy would be something like this:
    w, h = 128,128
    pw, ph = w+2,h+2
    padded_img = np.zeros((3,ph,pw))
    padded_img[:,1:ph-1,1:pw-1] = pic
    pad_i = padded_img[:,:,1:pw-1] - padded_img[:,:,0:pw-2]
    pad_j = padded_img[:,1:ph-1,:] - padded_img[:,0:ph-2,:]
    g_i = pad_i[:,1:ph-1,:]
    g_j = pad_j[:,:,1:pw-1]

Comment: Thx for your comment, it shed a most welcome light on the fact that I initially missed a paramount notion: y is in 3D ! Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thx for your time @Arnaud P! To make it easier, I am trying to approximate the gradient using 2D convolutions with Prewitt filters, it works when I load a RGB image but crashes with y_true and y_pred variables (I edited my question).